# A galvanic cell with a salt bridge for demonstration purposes (high school)

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, experimental-chemistry

I want to design a meaningful galvanic cell experiment for my high school science class. I am tempted to do an experiment without a salt bridge. Why? Because the most common batteries (i.e. lead batteries) only use one electrolyte ($\ce{H2SO4}$) and no salt bridge.

I am not aware of technology or processes that would justify the salt bridge. Anyone who can enlighten me? If so -- very grateful :)